# Salesforce page layout

Tags: lightning, page-layout

On Account object i have different page layouts for different profiles how do i edit the lightning page for these different profiles since they have different page layouts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the Lightning Page uses the Record Details component, then it will generate the correct "layout" [based on the page layout assignments](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.layouts_in_lex.htm&type=5). There is no editing to be done in the Lightning App Builder for the record details.

You can always create separate [Lightning Pages by Profile/RecordTYpe (activation)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages_activate.htm&type=5) or use [Dynamic (Forms) Lightning Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_migrate.htm&type=5) (custom objects, some standard objects) for further fine-grained control